# VBA ImportXml Data whithout headers

Tags: excel, vba

I need to import data from XML webpages (web service) into an Excel worksheet. It works perfectly fine, except the tables always add in headers.

My problem is that I want only one table and everytime I import new data to be added to the same..

Here is what I'm testing, but unefortunetly he creates a new table everytime I'm importing new data

```
Sub Importation()
'
' Importation Macro
' Import des données selon un parametre
' Touche de raccourci du clavier: Ctrl+Shift+I
'
Dim annee As String
Dim url As String
url = "http://www.simpleweb.org/wiki/WS/XML-based_Management"
Dim lngStartRow As Long
Dim withHeader As Boolean
    With ActiveSheet
        If .Range("$A$1") = "" Then
            withHeader = True
            lngStartRow = 1
       Else
            withHeader = False
            lngStartRow = .Range("$A$" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
       ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport url:=url, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=False, Destination:=Range("A" & lngStartRow)
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try `Overwrite:=True` and then you can add some additional VBA to remove the headers (since they are automatically/always added to the import data).